# how to delete part of text in line using powershell script

Tags: powershell

i need to write a simple script deleting part of line in text files.

For example this is a line i get from another program

```
TestConnection( '846part_no=993493criticity=length=2965 |WS|', "S31A 7", "A21.X3 9" );
```

and this is how i want to look

```
TestConnection( '846 |WS|', "S31A 7", "A21.X3 9" );
```

i am aware that there is some posts around here so if anyone have some ideas how i can create script deleting this or have a link to some posts just hit me some links
any help is very aprecieated

Comment: Use the regex-based `-replace` operator, described in detail in the linked duplicate. In your case: `$yourString -replace 'part_no=[^ ]+'`